# wglMakeCurrent fails on x64

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, 64-bit, wgl

I'm trying to create an OpenGL window on an x64 platform.
My initalization code works for x86/Win32, but fails for x64 at "wglMakeCurrent". I guess the problem is either in the setting of the pixelformat or in getting the DC (getDC()). I've tried different settings for my PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR already (assumed that the x64 implementation of OpenGL doesn't support that one I'm using), but had no success there. The debugger indicates that hdc may be corrupt - (its like 0xfffffffff10102e0) - however wglCreateContext returns an valid looking hglrc then (i.e. 0x0000000000010000). But even if I change the value from hdc on-the-fly to 0x0000000010102e0 (using the debugger, before the call of wglCreateContext) wglMakeCurrent still fails.

I'm on windows 8 with Visual Studio 12 RC 1.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Or is there maybe some limitation of the x64 OpenGL implementation?

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "OpenGL32.lib")

static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  switch (uMsg){
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
  WNDCLASSEX wc;
  ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance = nullptr;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
  wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClassTest";
  RegisterClassEx(&wc);
  DWORD dwStyle = WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU;
  RECT WindowRect;
  WindowRect.left = (long)0;
  WindowRect.right = (long)640;
  WindowRect.top = (long)0;
  WindowRect.bottom = (long)480;
  AdjustWindowRect(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE);
  HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
    "WindowClassTest",
    "WindowTitle",
    dwStyle,
    0, 0,
    WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left,
    WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    wc.hInstance,
    (LPVOID) nullptr);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
  ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
  SetFocus(hWnd);
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
  int         pf;
  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
  memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
  pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
  pfd.nVersion = 1;
  pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
  pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits = 32;
  pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
  if (pf == 0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "ChoosePixelFormat() failed:  "
      "Cannot find a suitable pixel format.", "Error", MB_OK);
  }
  if (SetPixelFormat(hdc, pf, &pfd) == FALSE) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "SetPixelFormat() failed:  "
      "Cannot set format specified.", "Error", MB_OK);
  }
  DescribePixelFormat(hdc, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);
  HGLRC hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
  if (!wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc)){
    MessageBox(NULL, "wglMakeCurrent() failed:  "
      "Cannot make context current.", "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  /* left out other unnecessary code here*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check what error code is returned via `GetLastError()`?

Comment: Before ChoosePixelFormat() GetLastError() returns 0x00000000 - so everything is fine until then. After ChoosePixelFormat() GetLastError() returns 0x0000007f - after wglCreateContext() 0x0000007a and after wglMakeCurrent() 0x00000006. The first error happens at ChoosePixelFormat(), so there might something wrong there...

Comment: If the other functions didn't fail then what `GetLastError()` returns after them is irrelevant, but if `wglMakeCurrent()` is failing then error 6 == `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` which suggests either the `hdc` or `hglrc` are invalid. Are you sure `wglCreateContext()` is succeeding?

Comment: Yes, `wglCreateContext()` doesn't return 0, so it's most likely succeeding.

Comment: Just a side note: You should not set a background brush for a OpenGL window. If there's a brush the window will flicker between the brush and the OpenGL drawing at each WM_ERASEBACKGND message (which usually happens before WM_PAINT), which is something you want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried compiling in VS 11 (even Express) to eliminate possibility of VS 12 RC1 being bugged? Asking because your example seems to work without errors for me when compiled with VS 11, both x86 and x64, also try running it on another machine and updating drivers.

Comment: I finally got to test it in different Environments - however I'm not sure if the results are good news or not. On an different PC with Visual Studio 11 it worked to call wglMakeCurrent without poping up the MessageBox. Same on Visual Studio 12 RC1 there. So it seems like mostly an graphics/OpenGL Driver Problem. But on the same machine with Visual Studio 11 it also works! So the Problem is only occuring in VS 12 RC1 (and only on my machine) - maybe I have to Switch back to VS 11, even if that means that I have to recompile all used libraries with the VS 11 C Runtime... Any ideas left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a very specific bug triggered in some cases when running 64 bit OpenGL applications within a Windows 8.x virtual machine. Based on the available reports (see below), it happens when

- the application has been compiled for x64 using Visual Studio >= 2012
- it is executed in Windows 8.x running inside a VM (Parallels/VMWare)

I am experiencing the same issue in the Parallels VM used to compile my application for Windows. A temporary workaround was to either use a 32 bit build or compile for 64 bit using a previous version of Visual Studio (I used 2010).

Importantly, Windows 8.x running on non-emulated hardware does *not* seem to be affected.

Links to other people mentioning this issue:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/b3fbe482-eba4-451d-bbed-3bc00b7c8bb5/wglmakecurrent-in-windows-8-64-bit-always-returns-false?forum=windowssdk
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780757/opengl-in-mfc-application-does-not-work-in-windows-8-64-bit